# MySQL and batch sql load

Tags: files, batch

I have sql files "separated" like this:

```
> tree sql
sql
├── adresse_trigger_update_before.sql
├── attribut_trigger_update_before.sql
├── categorie_trigger_update_before.sql
├── duplicate_records.sql
├── horaire_trigger_update_before.sql
├── partenaire_trigger_update_before.sql
├── personne_trigger_update_before.sql
└── produit_trigger_update_before.sql

0 directories, 8 files
>
```

Here are all my tries:

```
>mysql mydatabase -e "source sql/file1.sql"
>
>mysql mydatabase -e "source sql/*"
>ERROR at line 1: Failed to open file 'sql/*', error: 2
>cat sql/* > mysql mydatabase
>cat : option invalid -- 'p'
>mysql mydatabase -e "source sql/*"
>bash: sql/* : ambiguous redirect
```

How to load many files at once in MySQL?

Nota: there's only *one* problem I'm facing: load all the files in the "`sql`" folder **at once**. No other problem (I've removed user and password to be more precise about the actual problem).

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
find sql/ -type f | awk '{system("mysql -u root -pXXX -h localhost mydatabase < "$0)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"source code"/*` instead.

For the password issue , try quote it , e.g `mysql -u XX -p "XX"`

Comment: Hi, I have no password issue. I may not be clear enough, I've updated my question. I hope this is clearer now.